# Difference between " I borrowed some money from him" vs " I borrowed some money of him"

Tags: prepositions

Which sentence is correct?
I have seen "I borrowed money of him" on the net before.
As far as I am concerned, "I borrowed some money from him" seems to be right.

However, I have seen the follwing two sentences a lot.
"I will do what is expected from me."
"I will do what is expected of me."

Is "I will do what is expected from me"  the same as "I will do what is expected of me."?
If these two sentences can be interchangeably used, 
are "I borrowed some money from him." and "I borrowed some money of him." can be interchangeably used, too?

It is so confusing for me.

If any of native speakers can explain the difference between these two, I'd appreicate it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have read the sentence incorrectly.

> I borrowed some money **of** him

is not correct, but

> I borrowed some money **off** (of) him

is fine.  "Borrow off [(of) someone]" is a common phrasal verb.  Example:

> I lost my wallet at the bar, but I was able to borrow a few dollars **off of a stranger**, enough to take the bus home.

Comment: “Out of” for the battery and phone...

Comment: @SolarMike  Yeah, that's better.

Answer (score 0):

I think “I will do what is expected of me” is more commonly used than “I will do what is expected from me”- but they mean the same thing- “I will do what some person (or people) thinks I should be doing”.

“I borowed some money from him” and “I borrowed some money *off* him” mean the same thing. You would use “off” or “off of”, not “of” by itself. Both of these mean “He lent me some money”.